# Android Front Facing Camera Android 4.0.3 ICS Start Failed

Tags: java, android, camera, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, recorder

I'm trying to create a Android app that records a video from the front facing camera. The preview works fine, but as soon as i start recording the app crashes with the error "java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed." I've tried the same with the rear facing camera, but it has the same problem. Im working on a Samsung Tab 2 P5110 which is running Android ICS 4.0.3.

This is my Actvity class that shows the preview and should start the recording.

> ```
>     import java.io.IOException;
>     import java.lang.reflect.Method;
>     import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
>     import java.lang.reflect.Field;
>
>     import android.app.Activity;
>     import android.content.Intent;
>     import android.hardware.Camera;
>     import android.media.CamcorderProfile;
>     import android.media.MediaRecorder;
>     import android.os.Bundle;
>     import android.os.CountDownTimer;
>     import android.util.Log;
>     import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
>     import android.view.SurfaceView;
>     import android.view.View;
>     import android.view.Window;
>     import android.view.WindowManager;
>     import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
>     import android.widget.ProgressBar;
>     import android.widget.TextView;
>     import android.widget.FrameLayout;
>
>     public class VideoActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
>     SurfaceHolder.Callback, MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener {
>
>       MediaRecorder recorder;
>       SurfaceHolder holder;
>       Camera camera;
>
>       boolean recording = false;
>       public static final String TAG = "VIDEOCAPTURE";
>       private int show_id;
>       private CamcorderProfile mProfile;
>       private CountDownTimer cdt = null;
>
>       private static final int max_length_in_ms = 30000;
>
>
>       @Override 
>       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
>       {
>           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>
>           requestWindowFeature( Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE );
>           getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN );
>
>           show_id = getIntent().getIntExtra(Database.SHOW_ID, -1);
>
>           camera = this.openFrontFacingCamera(); // frontfacing camera
>
>                   camera = camera.open(); //rearfacing
>
>           recorder = new MediaRecorder();
>           recorder.setCamera(camera);
>
>
>           setContentView(R.layout.video);
>
>           FrameLayout cameraView = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.CameraView);
>
>           CameraSurfaceView cameraSurface = new CameraSurfaceView(getBaseContext(), camera);
>           cameraView.addView(cameraSurface);
>
>           holder = cameraSurface.getHolder();
>
>           cameraView.setClickable(true);
>           findViewById(R.id.recBtn).setOnClickListener(this);
>       }
>
>       private void initRecorder() {
>           recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
>           recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
>
>           recorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW));
>
>
>           recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/videotemp.mp4");
>           recorder.setMaxDuration(VideoActivity.max_length_in_ms); 
>           recorder.setMaxFileSize(50000000); // Approximately 50 megabytes
>       }
>
>       private void prepareRecorder() {
>           recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
>
>           try {
>               recorder.prepare();
>           } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
>               e.printStackTrace();
>               finish();
>           } catch (IOException e) {
>               e.printStackTrace();
>               finish();
>           }
>       }
>
>       public void onClick(View v) {
>           if (recording) {
>               recorder.stop(); 
>               recorder.release();
>               recording = false;
>               camera.release();
>               Log.v(TAG, "Recording Stopped");
>               // Let's initRecorder so we can record again
>               Intent intent = new Intent(this, UploadActivity.class);
>               intent.putExtra(Database.SHOW_ID, show_id);
>               intent.putExtra(Database.FILENAME, "/sdcard/videotemp.mp4");
>               intent.putExtra(Database.EXTENTION, ".mp4");
>               startActivity(intent);
>               finish();
>           } else {
>               recording = true;
>
>               initRecorder();
>
>               prepareRecorder();
>
>               recorder.start(); 
>
>               ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.videoProgress);
>               pb.setMax(VideoActivity.max_length_in_ms);
>
>               this.cdt = new CountDownTimer(VideoActivity.max_length_in_ms, 50) {
>
>                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {  
>                        ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.videoProgress);
>
>                        pb.setProgress( VideoActivity.max_length_in_ms - (int)((millisUntilFinished) )); 
>                    }
>
>                    public void onFinish() {
>                        ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.videoProgress);
>                        pb.setProgress(100);
>                    }
>                 };
>                 this.cdt.start();
>
>               Log.v(TAG, "Recording Started");
>           }
>       }
>
>       private Camera openFrontFacingCamera() {
>             Camera camera = null;
>
>             // Look for front-facing camera, using the Gingerbread API.
>             // Java reflection is used for backwards compatibility with
>             // pre-Gingerbread APIs.
>             try {
>                 Class<?> cameraClass = Class.forName("android.hardware.Camera");
>                 Object cameraInfo = null;
>                 Field field = null;
>                 int cameraCount = 0;
>                 Method getNumberOfCamerasMethod = cameraClass
>                         .getMethod("getNumberOfCameras");
>                 if (getNumberOfCamerasMethod != null) {
>                     cameraCount = (Integer) getNumberOfCamerasMethod.invoke(null,
>                             (Object[]) null);
>                 }
>                 Class<?> cameraInfoClass = Class
>                         .forName("android.hardware.Camera$CameraInfo");
>                 if (cameraInfoClass != null) {
>                     cameraInfo = cameraInfoClass.newInstance();
>                 }
>                 if (cameraInfo != null) {
>                     field = cameraInfo.getClass().getField("facing");
>                 }
>                 Method getCameraInfoMethod = cameraClass.getMethod("getCameraInfo",
>                         Integer.TYPE, cameraInfoClass);
>                 if (getCameraInfoMethod != null && cameraInfoClass != null
>                         && field != null) {
>                     for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++) {
>                         getCameraInfoMethod.invoke(null, camIdx, cameraInfo);
>                         int facing = field.getInt(cameraInfo);
>                         if (facing == 1) { // Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT
>                             try {
>                                 Method cameraOpenMethod = cameraClass.getMethod(
>                                         "open", Integer.TYPE);
>                                 if (cameraOpenMethod != null) {
>                                     camera = (Camera) cameraOpenMethod.invoke(null,
>                                             camIdx);
>                                     mProfile = CamcorderProfile
>                                             .get(camIdx, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW);
>                                 }
>                             } catch (RuntimeException e) {
>                                 Log.e(TAG,
>                                         "Camera failed to open: "
>                                                 + e.getLocalizedMessage());
>                             }
>                         }
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>             // Ignore the bevy of checked exceptions the Java Reflection API throws
>             // - if it fails, who cares.
>             catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
>                 Log.e(TAG, "ClassNotFoundException" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
>             } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
>                 Log.e(TAG, "NoSuchMethodException" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
>             } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
>                 Log.e(TAG, "NoSuchFieldException" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
>             } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
>                 Log.e(TAG, "IllegalAccessException" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
>             } catch (InstantiationException e) {
>                 Log.e(TAG, "InstantiationException" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
>             } catch (SecurityException e) {
>                 Log.e(TAG, "SecurityException" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
>             } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
>               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>               e.printStackTrace();
>           } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
>               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>               e.printStackTrace();
>           }
>
>             if (camera == null) {
>                 // Try using the pre-Gingerbread APIs to open the camera.
>                 try {
>                     camera = Camera.open();
>                 } catch (RuntimeException e) {
>                     Log.e(TAG, "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
>                 }
>             }
>
>             return camera;
>         }
>
>     }
> ```

For the preview I'm working with a extended version of SurfaceView

> ```
>  package nl.raakict.android.VideoCapture;
>     import java.io.IOException;
>
>     import android.content.Context;
>     import android.hardware.Camera;
>     import android.util.Log;
>     import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
>     import android.view.SurfaceView;
>
>     public class CameraSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
>         private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
>         private Camera mCamera;
>
>         public CameraSurfaceView(Context context, Camera camera) {
>             super(context);
>             mCamera = camera;
>
>             // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
>             // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
>             mHolder = getHolder();
>             mHolder.addCallback(this);
>             // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
>             mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
>         }
>
>         public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
>             // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
>             try {
>                 mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
>                 mCamera.startPreview();
>             } catch (IOException e) {
>                 Log.d("DEBUG", "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
>             }
>
>
>         }
>
>         public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
>
>         }
>
>         public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
>             // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
>             // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.
>
>             if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
>               // preview surface does not exist
>               return;
>             }
>
>             // stop preview before making changes
>             try {
>                 mCamera.stopPreview();
>             } catch (Exception e){
>               // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
>             }
>
>             // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
>             // reformatting changes here
>
>             // start preview with new settings
>             try {
>                 mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
>                 mCamera.startPreview();
>
>             } catch (Exception e){
>                 Log.d("DEBUG", "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.